# Magento get attribute code from filter.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the attribute code from the filter.phtml template file. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$_item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode()`

The above line of code can be used to get the attribute code when it is in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for asking this I actually needed it today too!

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using Magento Community 1.7.0.2

Comment: I just found solution:  `$_item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()`

Answer (score 4):

It will works only if filter is attribute bu for category it will not work
so you have to write like

```
echo $_filter->getType();
if($_filter->getType()=='catalog/layer_filter_attribute')
{
    echo $_filter->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@Posuk13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047072/posuk13) comment at [@Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377269/darren)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939858/806975), but to get the attribute code outside the items loop, you could use:

```
$this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()
```

(Tested on Magento 1.9 Community Edition)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in the context of **$this** being the class in use in **filter.phtml** the following prints/returns the attribute code:-

```
<?php echo $this->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode() ?>
```